# How can you recover more quickly from being knocked down?

Tags: guild-wars-2

The Guardian skill `Contemplation of Purity` converts conditions you are suffering from into boons. It also says that it "breaks stun".

This has me wondering if it works for allowing me to stand up after having been knocked over. If not, are there any other ways that I would be able to stand up more quickly after being knocked over?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knock Down counts as stun, so any skill that breaks stun will cancel the knockdown state early.

Contemplation of Purity is not the only guardian skill that can do this; any skill with "Breaks Stun" can be used to do so.

For Guardians, this includes `Save Yourselves`, `Stand Your Ground`, and `Judge's Intervention`.

Comment: Additional info, http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Stun_break